# Application times out when importing scipy.optimize

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scipy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to launch a Python Flask application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything works fine, until I add this line to one of my modules:

```
import scipy.optimize
```

If I add that line, I get the following message in the error logs:

```
Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
```

I believe SciPy is correctly installed, as I've SSHed into the EC2 instance and confirmed that it is listed in `/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

With the virtual environment still activated, I also run a simple script that uses SciPy functionality and it worked fine.  I also confirmed that Python 2.7.5 is used.

Using `from scipy import optimize` instead of `import scipy.optimize` results in the same error.

Does anybody have an idea what is causing this error or how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt that you can link to and are you using numpy as well?

Comment: Have you tried running python in verbose mode? E.g. `python -v -c 'import scipy.optimize'`

Comment: Is `scipy.optimize` imported only when handling a request? Will it help to import it during application startup instead? If its not the case - it is not clear where the timeout actually comes from.

Answer (score 0):

From a thread here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/TmGDM35jOJ8

Somebody suggests:
Add the following line

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to apache2/conf/httpd.conf and restart apache.

Alternatively, I've had success doing this

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cg
```

from a wsgi app in elastic beanstalk.  Maybe being specific on what you need will speed up the import time.

Comment: AFAIK doing `from scipy.optimize import fmin_cg` doesn't improve performance at all. Python still has to load `scipy` and `optimize` and then extract `fmin_cg` from `optimize`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because importing the stated module takes longer than the environment allows. You will either have to limit the amount of features you import (recommended), or manually increase the maximum amount of time allowed for import.